# FFMPEG image capture only executes partially on cron

Tags: macos, command-line, video, cron

I have the following shell script:

*DailyScript.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
now="/Users/mydir/Downloads/LIDOPRO/Captures/$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p').jpg"
"/Users/mydir/Downloads/LIDOPRO/ffmpeg" -ss 0.5 -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0" -frames:v 1 -t 1 "$now"
```

It produces an image through my FaceTime camera when I run the script manually in shell, as follows:

```
$ /Users/mydir/Downloads/LIDOPRO/DailyScript.sh
```

And the output I get is the following

```
ffmpeg version N-106916-ge71d5156c8-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      57. 24.101 / 57. 24.101
  libavcodec     59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100
  libavformat    59. 23.100 / 59. 23.100
  libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavfilter     8. 38.100 /  8. 38.100
  libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7f88f3004f00] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
0: could not seek to position 63537.297
Input #0, avfoundation, from '0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 63536.797200, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 640x480, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8018000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8040000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8050000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8060000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8070000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8080000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f8090000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f80a0000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f88f8008000] [swscaler @ 0x7f88f80b0000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/Users/caineardayfio/Downloads/LIDOPRO/Captures/2022_05_17_12_57_PM.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.23.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, progressive), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.28.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.2 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=N/A speed=0.232x    
video:20kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Everything works perfectly fine and the image is output.

So, I created a cron job to run the script automatically, as follows:

```
* * * * * /Users/caineardayfio/Downloads/LIDOPRO/DailyScript.sh 2> /tmp/error.txt 1> /tmp/output.txt
```

However, this cronjob does not actually work. No photo is produced and the script seems to execute, but only partially:
*error.txt*

```
ffmpeg version N-106916-ge71d5156c8-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      57. 24.101 / 57. 24.101
  libavcodec     59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100
  libavformat    59. 23.100 / 59. 23.100
  libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavfilter     8. 38.100 /  8. 38.100
  libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe5af104580] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
```

*output.txt* is empty

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I'd like the image to be produced.

Comment: Is macOS blocking it—not permitting ffmpeg polling your camera when invoked in this new way? Anything relevant in System Prefs, Security & Privacy, Privacy, Camera?

Comment: Could also try launchd (cron is deprecated). For example, here's a poorly-written launchagent job: [com.ardayfio.daily.plist](https://pst.klgrth.io/paste/of3h5/raw). When saved to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, and loaded with `launchctl bootstrap gui/$(whoami) ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ardayfio.daily.plist`, it runs every minute like your cronjob. [Decent writeup](https://davidhamann.de/2018/03/13/setting-up-a-launchagent-macos-cron/). [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html).